# How do I print what the user picks?

Tags: python

```
black_v = []
red_v = []
green_v = []
yellow_v = []
blue_v = []
magenta_v = []
cyan_v = []
white_v = []
nums_8 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

print("\n\u001b[31m\nEMEGENCY MEETING")

vote = input("\n\u001b[37mWho do you vote for?:\n[1] Black\n[2] Red\n[3] Green\n[4] Yellow\n[5] Blue\n[6] Magenta\n[7] Cyan\n[8] White\nEnter the number (1-8):>>> ")

while vote in nums_8:
    if vote == '1':
    black_v.append(1)
    break
```

My question is instead of making a 'if statement' for every number, is there a way I can just write something down and if the user enters '1', the program will append 1 to 'black_v' and if he enters '3', the program appends 1 to 'green_v'. Tell me how do do this in Python 3.x not 2.

Comment: Try using Make 2d list

Comment: Use a dictionary: `{"black": [], "red": [], ... }` and let them type the name instead of a number.

Comment: Can you guys tell me how to do it then.

Comment: ok but then how do I complete it? @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of separate variables.

```
votes = {
    "black": [],
    "red": [],
    "green": [],
    "yellow": [],
    "blue": [],
    "magenta": [],
    "cyan": [],
    "white": []
}

print("\n\u001b[31m\nEMEGENCY MEETING")


while True:
    vote = input("\n\u001b[37mWho do you vote for? (black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white) >>> ")
    if vote in votes:
        votes[vote].append(1)
        break
    else:
        Print("That's not a valid vote, try again")
```

Comment: The dict has to match the input. for ex: if the user enters `red`, the if statement won't work. Dont you think?

Comment: @Abdullah, please chage Barmar's code to `if vote+'_v' in votes: votes[vote+'_v'].append(1)`. That will take care of the `_v` in the dict

Comment: I forgot to remove all the `_v`, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

### MADE SOME UPDATES!

You could try this where you can put your list in a python dictionary and its key is the number value inputted by the user. So whatever the user enters is it gets the list in correspond to that particular number then `appends` it. Sorry the list wasn't a good idea... I knew something was off and the thing I was thinking was a dictionary.

Take a look at the sample output where when you enter `2` it will append the input data on the `red_v` list since it is `2` so on the dictionary the key `2` with a value of a `red_v` list will `append` the input of the user.

```
black_v = []
red_v = []
green_v = []
yellow_v = []
blue_v = []
magenta_v = []
cyan_v = []
white_v = []

nums_8 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

vs = {
1:black_v,
2:red_v,
3:green_v,
4:yellow_v,
5:blue_v,
6:magenta_v,
7:cyan_v,
8:white_v
}



print("\n\u001b[31m\nEMEGENCY MEETING")

vote = input("\n\u001b[37mWho do you vote for?:\n[1] Black\n[2] Red\n[3] Green\n[4] Yellow\n[5] Blue\n[6] Magenta\n[7] Cyan\n[8] White\nEnter the number (1-8):>>> ")


vs[int(vote)].append(vote)


print("Output in red_v list")
print(vs[2])




'''
while vote in nums_8:
    if vote == '1':
        black_v.append(1)
        break
'''
```

**Output:**

```
[1] Black
[2] Red
[3] Green
[4] Yellow
[5] Blue
[6] Magenta
[7] Cyan
[8] White
Enter the number (1-8):>>> 2
Output in red_v list
['2']
```

Comment: Why do you have `list()` at the beginning of the list?

Comment: You voted for black, but it added to red because of `+1`

Comment: @StackOffended , when I input 2 i get '[]' as an answer using ur code. Why?>

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Avoid "hardcoding" when it's possible. This way you can also add some more values in `labels` and it'll work as always (like I added a `<skip>` value)

```
labels = ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Magenta', 'Cyan', 'White', '<skip>']
num_to_labels = { str(num + 1):label for num, label in enumerate(labels)}
num_to_votes =  { str(num + 1):0     for num, label in enumerate(labels)}

print('\n\u001b[31m\nEMERGENCY MEETING')
print('\n\u001b[37mWho do you vote for?:')
for num, label in num_to_labels:
    print(f'[{num}] {label}')

vote = input(f'Enter the number (1-{len(labels)}):>>> :')
while not vote in num_to_votes.keys():
    vote = input(f'Wrong number, repeat (1-{len(labels)}):>>> :')

num_to_votes[vote] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
colors = {"Black": [], "Red": [], "Green": [], "Yellow": [], "Blue": [], "Magenta": [], "Cyan": [], "White": []}

_map_of_colors = {num: color for num, color in enumerate(colors, start=1)}
# {1: 'Black', 2: 'Red', 3: 'Green', 4: 'Yellow', 5: 'Blue', 6: 'Magenta', 7: 'Cyan', 8: 'White'}

msg_colors_options = '\n'.join([f'[{key}] {color}' for key, color in _map_of_colors.items()])
# [1] Black
# [2] Red
# [3] Green
# [4] Yellow
# [5] Blue
# [6] Magenta
# [7] Cyan
# [8] White

# f-string only python3.6+
msg_input = f"""\u001b[31m
EMEGENCY MEETING
\u001b[37m
{msg_colors_options}
Enter the number (1-8):>>>"""
#
#
# EMEGENCY MEETING
#
# [1] Black
# [2] Red
# [3] Green
# [4] Yellow
# [5] Blue
# [6] Magenta
# [7] Cyan
# [8] White
# Enter the number (1-8) or 0 to exit:>>>

while True:
    option = input(msg_input)
    if not option.isalnum() or int(option) not in range(len(_map_of_colors)):
        input(f"\u001b[31mValue {option} isn't valid.\u001b[37m\nPress <ENTER> to continue.")
        continue
    # cast int
    option = int(option)

    if option == 0:
        # show values
        print("Values: ", colors)
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    # get color name in map
    color_name = _map_of_colors[option]
    # get color array by name and append.
    colors[color_name].append(option)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
candidates = [['black_v', 0],['red_v', 0],['green_v', 0], ['yellow_v', 0], ['blue_v', 0], ['magenta_v',0], ['cyan_v',0], ['white_v', 0]]


 print("\n\u001b[31m\nEMEGENCY MEETING")

vote = input("\n\u001b[37mWho do you vote for?:\n[1] Black\n[2] Red\n[3] Green\n[4] 
Yellow\n[5] Blue\n[6] Magenta\n[7] Cyan\n[8] White\nEnter the number (1-8):>>> ")
candidates[int(vote) - 1][1] += 1
```

**Input**

```
   EMEGENCY MEETING

   Who do you vote for?:
  [1] Black
  [2] Red
  [3] Green
  [4] Yellow
  [5] Blue
  [6] Magenta
  [7] Cyan
  [8] White
  Enter the number (1-8):>>> 1
```

**Output**

```
  print(candidates)
```

`[['black_v', 1], ['red_v', 0], ['green_v', 0], ['yellow_v', 0], ['blue_v', 0], ['magenta_v', 0], ['cyan_v', 0], ['white_v', 0]]`